# findOneAndUpdate does not update document

Tags: javascript, mongoose, jestjs

I have the following method to update my document:

```
const findAndDisabledAlert = id => (
  AlertModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, { $set: { status: 'D' } }, { new: true }, (err, alt) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    return alt;
  })
);
```

But this don't update the document and return null, I also tried without the "$set" but getting the same result.

The following test create the alert but does not change the status:

```
test('Should create, find and disable an alert', async () => {
    const currencyAlert = {
      name: 'VTC',
      pair: 'BTC',
      price: 0.00009241,
      condition: 'H',
      status: 'D',
      exchange: 'BITTREX',
    };

    const alert = await createAlert(currencyAlert);
    const alertDisabled = await findAndDisabledAlert(alert.id);

    expect(alertDisabled.status).toBe('D');
  });
```

Comment: Please can you post an example document from your Database? As well as an example of what `alert` looks like.

Comment: You can't return an async result like `alt` from a method like `findAndDisabledAlert`. You'd have to use a callback or promise.

Comment: @Jack is the same like the test but with an _id

Answer (score 0):

Should the statment const alertDisabled = await findAndDisabledAlert(alert.id);
 not be

```js
const alertDisabled = await findAndDisabledAlert(alert._id);
```

Comment: You can get the id of the document without the underscore